# WP Calendar Shortcode not working on my theme

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm using [WP Calendar plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-calendar/) on my development site. [The documentation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-calendar/faq) says that I can use the tag `{event_calendar}` on my template to render the calendar.

This is the code am using on my template page.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[event_calendar]') ?>
```

When I look at the Chrome Console, There is no error. There is a Javascript file that is loaded: `fullcalendar.min.js`.

jQuery 1.9 loads up in the header.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: the plugin's FAQ does not mention any shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell how can make this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so: the doc says you should just put {event_calendar} in your page template (between `<?php ?>` tags. So it's a tag you can use in your theme, NOT a shortcode.